# Getting two random non consecutive and unique elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Hi I am trying of getting two unique random elements from a list that are not consecutive. The array is formed as following

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Monday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Tuesday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Wednesday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Thursday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 5, "name": "Friday", "workers": []},
]
```

And I managed to get two unique elements as following :

```
 getTwoNonConsecutiveDays = () => {
    var days = require('./weeks.json');

    let selected = [];
    let randomday = () => {
      const shuffled = days.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

      // Get sub-array of first n elements after shuffled
      selected = shuffled.slice(0, 2);
```

However when I am trying to put condition not to be consecutive is not working

```
      if (selected[0].id === selected[1].id) {

     console.log('greseala')}

     selected[0].id
```

Comment: What you mean by "_not working_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Don't "shuffle" the array. Generate two numbers in the range `0..(days.length - 1)` and use these to access the elements. Then just generate numbers until your condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Shuffling (especially, wtih `.sort()`) does not guarantee that 2 adjacent elements won't stay adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

You may go, like that:

- pick randomly centered window of 3 consequent items (2 if started on first array item) and get the one in the middle as the first item
- remove selected triplet (e.g. using `Array.prototype.splice()`) to avoid picking first random item or its neighbors
- pick randomly second random item from those that left

```js
const src = [{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]},{"id":2,"name":"Tuesday","workers":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Wednesday","workers":[]},{"id":4,"name":"Thursday","workers":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Friday","workers":[]}],

     getRandomPair = ([...a]) => {
        const {random} = Math,
              windowPos = 0|random()*(a.length-1),
              e1 = a.splice(windowPos, windowPos ? 3 : 2)[windowPos && 1],    
              e2 = a[0|random()*a.length]
        return [e1,e2]
      }
      
console.log(getRandomPair(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it that way:

```
var days = require('./weeks.json');
 function randomIndex(array){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
 }
 
 function randomPair(array){
        var index1 = randomIndex(array), index2;
    do{
        index2 = randomIndex(array);
    }while(Math.abs(index1 - index2) < 2);
    return [array[index1], array[index2]];
 }
console.log(randomPair(days));
```

**Note:** While loop and exit condition are inappropriate for small arrays, as @Yevgen Gorbunkov said in comment. An additional if condition  can be added for checking the length of the array.

**Update:** While condition update based on @Andreas comment, use of Math.abs instead of multiple checks.

Comment: This seems to be prone to stuck into endless loop if accidentally fed with array of 3 items. Besides, for small arrays the chances of picking inappropriate second item are pretty high, so it will consume CPU cycles unnecessarily to ***guess*** the item that passes the condition.

Comment: `do { ... } while (Math.abs(index1 - index2) < 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following logic:

- Create a loop with `n` as limit.
- Create 2 variables:

  - `List` to hold items.
  - `map` to hold indexes that were generated.
- Loop over and generate random index. To keep it in bounds, use  `Math.floor( Math.random() * array.length )`
- Now check in `map` if the neighboring elements exists. If yes, you can go to next value.
- On finding unique index, add it to `map` and pust item to `list`.

```js
function getNonConsecutiveDays(array, n) {
  const list = [];
  const map = {};
  Array
    .from({ length: n })
    .forEach(() => {
      let index = Math.floor( Math.random() * array.length );
      
      if( map[ index + 1 ] || map[ index - 1]) {
        index = (index + 1) % array.length;
      }
      let item = array[index];
      map[ index ] = true;
      list.push(item)
    });
    return list;
}

const data = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Monday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Tuesday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Wednesday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 4, "name": "Thursday", "workers": []},
  {"id": 5, "name": "Friday", "workers": []},
];

console.log( getNonConsecutiveDays(data, 2) )
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why your code outputs the array of 2 same items every once in a while?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I figured out:

1. Choose the index `a` of the first element from the range `[0, arr.length)`.
2. If `a == 0` or `a == arr.length - 1`, the first element has only 1 neighbour. Otherwise, it has 2 ones. So the number of possible choices of the second index is equal to `arr.length - 1 - neighbours`.
3. Choose the index `b` of the second element from the range `[0, arr.length - 1 - neighbours)`
4. If `b >= a - 1`, add `1 + neighbours` to `b`.

And here's the code:

```js
arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

a = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length); // 1.
neighbours = 2; // 2.
if (a == 0 || a == arr.length - 1) neighbours = 1;
b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1 - neighbours)); // 3.
if (b >= a - 1) b += neighbours + 1; // 4.
    
console.log(arr[a], arr[b]);
```

It should be guaranteed that the length of your array is greater than 3.