# Select only two elements from an array for each element from antoher array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

So I am having 10 different elements in an object( I called them workers ) and I am trying to give them two days (to work each). The days cannot be consecutive.

I managed to create a function that generates two different and non-consecutive days

```
 getTwoNonConsecutiveDays = () => {
    let saved = [];
    var days = require('./weeks.json');
    let randomIndex = (days) => {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * days.length);
    };

    let randomPair = (days) => {
      var index1 = randomIndex(days),
        index2;
      do {
        index2 = randomIndex(days);
      } while (
        index1 == index2 ||
        index1 == index2 + 1 ||
        index1 == index2 - 1
      );
      return [days[index1], days[index2]];
    };
     ;
    saved.push(...randomPair(days));
   return JSON.stringify(randomPair(days))
  };
```

and a function that selects all workers and give two days each

```
  getWorkers = () => {
    var workers = require('./workers.json');
    return  workers.map((a) => 
    
    <View>
      <Text>{this.getTwoNonConsecutiveDays()}</Text>
       <Text key={a.id.toString()}>{a.id}</Text></View>
   );
  };
```

The output of the current test is :

```
 [{"id":3,"name":"Wednesday","workers":[]},{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]}]worker name is :1
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.607]  LOG      [{"id":4,"name":"Thursday","workers":[]},{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]}]worker name is :2
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.608]  LOG      [{"id":3,"name":"Wednesday","workers":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Friday","workers":[]}]worker name is :3
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.608]  LOG      [{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]},{"id":4,"name":"Thursday","workers":[]}]worker name is :4
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.609]  LOG      [{"id":4,"name":"Thursday","workers":[]},{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]}]worker name is :5
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.610]  LOG      [{"id":3,"name":"Wednesday","workers":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Friday","workers":[]}]worker name is :6
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.612]  LOG      [{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Wednesday","workers":[]}]worker name is :7
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.613]  LOG      [{"id":5,"name":"Friday","workers":[]},{"id":2,"name":"Tuesday","workers":[]}]worker name is :8
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.614]  LOG      [{"id":3,"name":"Wednesday","workers":[]},{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]}]worker name is :9
[Mon Jul 06 2020 21:28:36.615]  LOG      [{"id":4,"name":"Thursday","workers":[]},{"id":1,"name":"Monday","workers":[]}]worker name is :10
```

Now the issue is that a single day cannot be taken by more than two workers. My desired outcome is that each worker will have two days, but each day will not be selected for more than two times for a single worker. The worker id can be seen at the final of every output specified as a number.

Comment: It would help if you post the input data and expected output data instead of a function that doesn't work.

Comment: I expect to have a list that each day will be found on just a maximum of two workers .

Comment: Are the items in the days array unique?

Comment: *'...I managed to create...'* You seem to be using [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758438/11299053) from your previous question without even bothering to accept that. Though it was not a good choice, anyways, as doing guesswork until proper pair is found is excessive way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with some cheating . . . there are notes to explain within the code, though to summarize its 3 parts: first assign 1 worker per day randomly, then for each day figure out the available options, and finally assign those options. I am unable to get the 3rd part to successfully complete 100% of the time (~98%) so I run the function recursively if it fails. Note, this is not based directly off your code, but rather demonstrates the algorithm in general.

```js
//mock values
const days = {
  "Day1": [],
  "Day2": [],
  "Day3": [],
  "Day4": [],
  "Day5": [],
  "Day6": [],
  "Day7": [],
  "Day8": [],
  "Day9": [],
  "Day10": []
}
//mock values
const workers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

//assign a worker to each day at random;
function partA(workers, days) {
  //copy made for push mutation
  const daysCopy = { ...days
  };
  //copy made for splice mutation
  const workersCopy = [...workers];
  //a worker is selected at random, then spliced from the worker array to prevent being selected again
  Object.keys(daysCopy).forEach(key => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * workersCopy.length);
    daysCopy[key] = [workersCopy.splice(random,1)[0]];
  })      
  return partB(workers, daysCopy);
}

//determine what workers are available for each remaining slot
function partB(workers, days) {
  //create an object map of available workers
  const workerMap = {};
  //for each day check who the current, previous, and next day's worker is, then add all others to object map
  Object.keys(days).forEach((key, index) => {
    const current = days[key][0];
    const prev = days[Object.keys(days)[index - 1]] ? days[Object.keys(days)[index - 1]][0] : null;
    const next = days[Object.keys(days)[index + 1]] ? days[Object.keys(days)[index + 1]][0] : null;
    const allowed = workers.filter(worker => [current, prev, next].indexOf(worker) < 0);
    workerMap[key] = allowed;
  })
  //pass daysCopy and workerMap to final part
  return partC(days, workerMap)
}

//randomly assign remaining workers
function partC(days, workerMap) {
  //create copy for push mutation
  const daysCopy = { ...days
  };
  //create copy for delete mutation
  let mapCopy = { ...workerMap
  };
  //while there remains available workers
  while (Object.keys(mapCopy).length) {
    //store keys for days with available workers
    const keys = Object.keys(mapCopy);
    //create object map for length of available workers per day
    const lengths = {};
    Object.keys(mapCopy).forEach(key => {
      lengths[key] = mapCopy[key].length;
    })
    //find the day with the least amount of options as this guarantees less chance of failure
    const shortestVal = Object.values(lengths).sort((a, b) => a - b)[0];
    const shortestKey = keys.find(key => lengths[key] === shortestVal)

    //randomly select an available option for the shortest day
    const options = mapCopy[shortestKey];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
    const selection = options[random];

    //this is where I cheat; 
    //if the assignment fails, it will recursively call itself; this occurs about 2% of the time
    if (typeof selection === "undefined") return partC(days, workerMap);
    //otherwise push the selection as the second worker for the day
    daysCopy[shortestKey] = [...daysCopy[shortestKey], selection];
    //remove that worker as an available option for all other days
    keys.forEach(key => {
      mapCopy[key] = mapCopy[key].filter(worker => worker !== selection);
    })
    //delete the resolved day from the availability map
    delete mapCopy[shortestKey];
  }


  //return days with assigned workers
  return daysCopy;
}

console.log((partA(workers, days)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add two days of work to each one and you only allow two workers per day, there is a problem: 10 workers distributed to two per day without repetition, the week would have to be 10 days.
But I am assuming that the array of days of the week only has 7 days, but if it has more days, for example, it has two and a half weeks, everything is fine.
That said, adapt this solution I made to your problem:

```js
// you can add as many consecutive days as you want
let weekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
// number of workers per day, in this case, it is doubled for two per day
let doubleDays = [...weekDays, ...weekDays];

let workers = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];

const getTwoNonConsecutiveDays = () => {
  let randomIndex = (days) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * days.length);
  };

  let index = randomIndex(doubleDays), index2;
  let indexWeekDay = weekDays.indexOf(doubleDays[index]), indexWeekDay2;

  doubleDays.splice(index, 1);
  let array = doubleDays.filter((filter) => !(filter === weekDays[indexWeekDay] || filter === weekDays[indexWeekDay === 0 ? weekDays.length - 1 : indexWeekDay - 1] || filter === weekDays[indexWeekDay === weekDays.length - 1 ? 0 : indexWeekDay + 1]));

  index2 = randomIndex(array);
  indexWeekDay2 = weekDays.indexOf(array[index2]);
  doubleDays.splice(index2, 1);
  return [weekDays[indexWeekDay], weekDays[indexWeekDay2]]
};

console.log(workers.map(() => (getTwoNonConsecutiveDays())));
```

Comment: - An engineer can do at most one half day shift in a day.
 - Each engineer should have completed one whole day of support in any 2 week period.
 - An engineer cannot have half day shifts on consecutive days.